# Using Breakpoints giving EXC_BAD_ACESSS in XCODE

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, exc-bad-access

Its been 5-6 months am working on XCODE. I am facing this problem for the first time.
Break point is best for me while debugging. 
But today I faced a problem, where ever I use breakpoint, first line just after the break point is generating 
**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0X0)**
, I have added the screen-Shot for the same.

Due to this problem, am not able to debug my code. Please Help. Thanks in advance

I really don't know why its showing so.[image: Xcode screen Shot]

Comment: which xcode version are you using? This was a known bug of one of the early xcode 5 releases (like 5.0.1 or 5.0.2, don't remember exactly which one)

Comment: @alvi
Yes am using Version 5.0.1 (5A2053), But I have been using this version from last 2-3 months and never faced the Problem. I didn't change any settings too.

Comment: try a recent xcode (you can run it alongside your current version if you don't feel like upgrading). I'm pretty sure this will solve your problem.